How can I change my code to obtain simpler form and brighter blinking dots
I want to obtain blinking dots one after one in one direction and then blinking have to go back, and all have to happen in the loop. I have created CSS code with Javascript according to first five dots. What can I do to make shorter all reqired code in CSS? Also I want to make not visible black backgrounds of the dots during blinking.


for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  const dots = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(dots).classList.add("dots");
}
body {
  background-color: #737373;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dots {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dots:nth-of-type(1)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bright 0.3s linear;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgb(255, 255, 255),
    0 0 5px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 12px 12px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.dots:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bright 0.3s linear;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgb(255, 255, 255),
    0 0 5px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 12px 12px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 0.25s;
}

.dots:nth-of-type(3)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bright 0.3s linear;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgb(255, 255, 255),
    0 0 5px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 12px 12px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.dots:nth-of-type(4)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bright 0.3s linear;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgb(255, 255, 255),
    0 0 5px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 12px 12px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 0.75s;
}

.dots:nth-of-type(5)::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bright 0.3s linear;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgb(255, 255, 255),
    0 0 5px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 12px 12px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes bright {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}




Why did this question get closed? Lack of focus? I only see one issue described -- maybe not in the best English. OK, there are two sentences that are questions, but that should not be the reason to close the question.

@chrwahl I agree, it seems that perfect English is a requirement here. The example is clear, an attempt was made, we have code and what it needs to do. We don't know why this is needed, nor what the problem is completing this code. That might be why it is closed, but people, you could have asked.

I haven't voted to close, but now that it is closed I'd like to ask what "I want to make not visible black backgrounds of the dots during blinking" means. I can't decide if the dots should be invisible when not blinking "on", or what else "not visible black backgrounds" might mean?

To do this with only CSS you need a selector for every dot and you need to know the number of dots. That's a ton of work and not really dynamic or extensible. Frankly, since you are already using Js, I'd suggest you script this rather than trying to leverage CSS. Thus this is really too broad especially since you are asking for two separate things here as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39875806/add-class-sequentially-to-a-series-of-elements

You could look into having just one blinking pseudo element on the parent and move it along the dots using animation steps to make it seem as though each dot is changing without having to explicitly code for each dot. You will need to know the number of dots though. And use the other pseudo element to overlay the blackness of each dot as it’s being blinked..

CSS can do this for you without needing to define the delays for every circle.
In this snippet, a before pseudo element moves along the circles in steps (see definition of CSS animation steps for more info) with color the same as the background. It will therefore briefly 'hide' the blackness of a circle.
The after pseudo element also moves along in the same steps, but has the blinking part as well.
This way it looks as though each circle is being individually 'blinked' in turn.
The CSS animation 'alternate' value is used to make the animations reverse and they are made infinite.


for (let i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
  const dots = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(dots).classList.add("dots");
}
body {
  --n: 40;
  /* number of circles */
  --w: 20px;
  /* width of a circle */
  --t: 0.3s;
  /* blink time */
  background-color: #737373;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.dots {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: var(--w);
  height: var(--w);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(var(--w) + 2px);
  /* a bit wider to compensate for occasional mis-alignment as the system tries to deal with part pixels */
  height: calc(var(--w) + 2px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: move calc(var(--n) * var(--t)) steps(var(--n)) infinite alternate;
  background-color: #737373;
}

body::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bright var(--t) linear infinite alternate, move calc(var(--n) * var(--t)) steps(var(--n)) infinite alternate;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgb(255, 255, 255),
    0 0 5px 5px rgb(255, 255, 255), 0 0 12px 12px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  left: 0;
}


@keyframes bright {

  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    left: calc((100% - (var(--n) * var(--w))) / calc(var(--n) + 1) - 1px);
  }

  100% {
    left: calc(100% - 1px);
  }
}



Note: CSS variables are used so that the calculation that has to be done to get the starting position of the first circle etc can be found easily using calc. In particular, in this case the justify-content value will determine what the gap is.
Also, I have kept the same HTML structure as in the question but would recommend using a container for the circles rather than body being the direct parent.

An idea with a single element and no JS


@property --o {
  syntax: "<number>";
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0; 
}
.box {
  --n: 10;   /* number of circles */
  --s: 30px; /* size of circle */
  --g: 15px; /* gap */
  --t: 0.3s; /* blink time */
  
  height: calc(var(--s) + var(--g));
  aspect-ratio: var(--n);
  background:
   radial-gradient(50% 50%,rgb(255 255 255/var(--o)) 50%,#0000) no-repeat,
   conic-gradient(#737373 0 0) no-repeat,
   radial-gradient(calc(var(--s)/2),#000 95%,#0000);
  background-size: calc(var(--s) + var(--g)) 100%;
  animation:
    bright var(--t) infinite,
    move calc(var(--n)*var(--t)) steps(var(--n),jump-none) infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% { background-position: left  }
  to { background-position: right }
}

@keyframes bright {
  50% {--o: 1}
}



body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: #737373;
}
<div class="box"></div>



And if you want an overflowing effect for the shadow, you can update like below:


.box {
  --n: 10;   /* number of circles */
  --s: 30px; /* size of circle */
  --g: 15px; /* gap */
  --t: 0.3s; /* blink time */
  
  height: calc(var(--s) + var(--g));
  aspect-ratio: var(--n);
  background:
   conic-gradient(#737373 0 0) no-repeat,
   radial-gradient(calc(var(--s)/2),#000 95%,#0000);
  background-size: calc(var(--s) + var(--g)) 100%;
  animation: move calc(var(--n)*var(--t)) steps(var(--n),jump-none) infinite alternate;
  position: relative;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #fff;
  filter: blur(10px);
  scale: 1.2;
  animation:
    bright var(--t) infinite,
    move-alt calc(var(--n)*var(--t)) steps(var(--n),jump-none) infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% { background-position: left  }
  to { background-position: right }
}

@keyframes move-alt {
  0% { left: 0%;  translate:  0   }
  to { left: 100%;translate: -100%}
}

@keyframes bright {
  50% {opacity: 1}
}



body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  background: #737373;
}
<div class="box"></div>



